# I can't set up **** clasp run ****

Tags: google-apps-script, visual-studio-code, clasp

**Purpose:**

To be able to use ***clasp run*** on VS Code

**I did...**

followed this instruction. https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md
And I could successfully finish steps 1 - 4. As long as I know, I could get everything I was expecting.

**Problem:**

But on step 5, I got this error message below, check this screenshot.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcLlY.png)

> Error 403: access_denied
> The developer hasn’t given you access to this app. It’s currently being tested and it hasn’t been verified by Google. If you think you should have access, contact the developer (xxxxxxxx@gmail.com).
> Learn more
> Request Details
> The content in this section has been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed or verified by Google.
> If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.
> access_type: offline
> response_type: code
> redirect_uri: http://localhost:38159
> client_id: xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
> scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.webapp.deploy

**Comment:**

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? And thank you for reading.

**Environment:**

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

OS Type: 64-bit

GNOME: 3.36.8

Windowing system: X11

IDE: VS Code: 1.66.2

Node.js: 16.13.0

clasp: 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Your project is still in testing; you either need to add the account you're trying to authorize as a test user, or set the project's publishing status to "In production" i.e. publish it.

Here's a video that shows you how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_NPvk0pk8g

The sidebar in that video isn't quite up to date however: I recommend searching for oauth in the top bar while having the appropriate project selected and clicking on `OAuth consent screen`.

[image: Like this]